# Keychain access in iOS for OAuth tokens

Tags: ios, oauth, keychain, data-protection, keychainitemwrapper

I'd like to use `Keychain Services` for iOS to store the OAuth access token and refresh token that my app need to perform Web services requests. I've been reading the [Keychain Services Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Security/Conceptual/keychainServConcepts/01introduction/introduction.html) and I downloaded the [GenericKeychain](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/GenericKeychain/Introduction/Intro.html) sample code, but I'm getting confused:

1. Code provided in document is different from the sample code... which approach should I follow?
2. I read somewhere that you need to enable `Data Protection` in Member Center for the App ID and its associated provisioning profile. However, I didn't read anything about enabling `Data Protection` in Xcode for the target's capabilities, and it seems that I could access the keychain anyway... this is weird, but I guess I should enable `Data Protection` in the Xcode project as well, right? Where is this `Data Protection` stuff described in Apple's docs? Is it somewhere said that I need to enable it for `Keychain` management? I don't find it...
3. Samples I found use the `kSecClassGenericPassword` class for the keychain items. Since I want to manage OAuth related information, is there any better class I should use? Maybe `kSecClassInternetPassword`? What is the difference with `kSecClassGenericPassword`?
4. Is it recommended to instantiate a kind of `KeychainWrapper` class, or would it be better to access keychain related methods as class methods?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Theres a bunch of keychain wrappers out there you can make use of that will eliminate a lot of this complexity for you. Some of them as simple as using NSUserDefaults.

Comment: @BeauYoung Thanks, I'm currently testing another one. But I still couldn't make clear about the questions 2 & 3...

Answer (score 0):

Q3:
According to Apple
[documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Security/Conceptual/keychainServConcepts/iPhoneTasks/iPhoneTasks.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30000897-CH208-SW1)

> You use Internet passwords for accessing servers and websites over the Internet, and generic passwords for any other password-protected service (such as a database or scheduling application).